# How to add a new column in a text file using python?

Tags: python, file, text, text-files

This is the initial text file:

```
Name        Height(m)   Weight(kg)  
Joe         1.82        72.57       
Mary        1.60        63.50       
Dion        1.90        90.71       
Kayla       1.72        66.31       
Jose        1.78        70.23       
Sofia       1.63        65.12       
Erik        1.98        92.21       
Sara        1.57        65.77
```

I am trying to add another column (BMI). I am able to do the calculations in python. I have opened the code in 'r+' form. My code is below:

```
open_file = open('data.txt', 'r+')

def clean_word(word):
    return word.strip().lower()

#clean_word(open_file)


line = open_file.readlines()  # READS ALL LINES, EACH LINE INDIVIDUALLY
line.pop(0)  # DELETES FIRST LINE


bmi_list = []
height_list = []
weight_list = []

new_file = open('data2.txt', 'w')

#file = open('data.txt', 'w+')

for word in line:
    word = clean_word(word)
    word_list = word.split()
    height = float(word_list[1])
    weight = float(word_list[2])
    bmi = '{:.2f}'.format(weight/height**2)
    bmi_list.append(bmi)
    word_list.insert(3, bmi)   # 'INSERTS BMI VALUES TO NORMAL LIST
    #print(word_list)
    height_list.append(height)
    weight_list.append(weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a new file and write out the existing line, plus the new data. So, create a new file, loop through the existing file, and write out each existing line with the new column appended to it.

```
new_file.write(existing_line + "\t" + new_data)
```

If you run into issues with the new line character at the end of the existing line, you can do this

```
new_file.write(existing_line.strip() + "\t" + new_data)
```

The "\t" character represents a tab

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use pandas to handle it as a dataframe https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html

Answer (score 0):

It is odd that you are storing bmi as a string and weight and height as floats.  You probably want something like this:

```
for word in line:
    word = clean_word(word)
    word_list = word.split()
    height = float(word_list[1])
    weight = float(word_list[2])
    bmi = weight/height**2
    bmi_list.append(bmi)
    height_list.append(height)
    weight_list.append(weight)
    print('{:.2f}   {:.2f}   {:.2f}'.format(height,weight,bmi))
```